# Knockout: Iterate over object and show value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js

I need some help with js/knockout/databindings.

In my code I am receiving an object like this:
[Received object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdzg8.png)

I wish to show the value in a dropdown, and the key should be stored as the value.
I tried using some knockout data-bind like this:

```
<select id="routeTable" class="form-control" data-bind="
                            options: availableRouteTables,
                            optionsText: availableRouteTables.key,
                            optionsValue: availableRouteTables.value,
                            value: selectedRouteTable,
                            optionsCaption: '- velg rutetabell -'"></select>
```

I know that "availableRouteTables.key" and "availableRouteTables.value" are wrong, but it was just to explain/show what I want.

As of now the object only looks like this in JS:

```
this.availableRouteTables = availableRouteTables;
```

In the dropdown it is shown like this:
[Dropdown failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa6tB.png)

Can someone help me with identifying the issue and fix it? 
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive the data you have to change it's structure to work with the options binding:

```
// Convert to array of objects with value and text properties
var availableRouteOptions = [];
for(var key in availableRouteTables) {
    availableRouteOptions.push({
    value: key,
    text: availableRouteTables[key]
  });
}
```

And you have to change your bindings:

```
options: availableRouteOptions,
optionsText: 'text',
optionsValue: 'value',
```

Comment: Worked with a tiny alteration. text: availableRouteTables[key] instead of data[key] :) Thank you so much!